# Opencart round price

Tags: opencart, rounding

I have to round up all the prices of `Opencart`. I used the method `round()` on function `calculate ()` in system / library and it works well. 
The problem is in the `total` that is not based on the prices rounded, but on the real ones. How can I fix this?

This is my code in tax.php:

```
public function calculate($value, $tax_class_id, $calculate = true) {
    if ($tax_class_id && $calculate) {
        $amount = $this->getTax($value, $tax_class_id);
        return round($value + $amount);
    }else{
        return round($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you've written.

Comment: Call `round()` on total price as well? Or, on the other side - You are probably rounding only values for displaying purposes, but when adding products to cart, the prices are not rounded anymore. Either round them again when adding into the cart, or round them globally in a DB once and You are done.